# Tar xvzf question

Tags: linux, compression, archiving, tar

Hi I use FC12 command : `tar xvfz GeoIP.dat.gz`

I get the errors

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

Whats the problem?

Comment: `/usr/bin/file` is your friend.  When a program is having trouble with an input file, try `file GeoIP.dat` to see if it is what you think it is.

Answer (score 9):

Based on the filename, it isn't a tar archive.

Try just using `gunzip GeoIP.dat.gz` which should give you GeoIP.dat.

Comment: @uname3455 If this answer worked out for you, consider accepting it as the best answer by clicking the check mark on the left.